# Is there an open source C++ library to read powerpoint files? Will reading .pdfs be easier than reading .pptx files?

Tags: open-source, library, c++, powerpoint

I am currently undertaking a project in C++ that requires me to read pptx files. I am wondering if there are some open-source C++ libraries which will allow me to read pptx files. The only one I could find till now is: Aspose which does not seem to be open-source.

I am open to other alternatives to solve my problem. Will converting .pptx to .pdfs make reading them easier? The .pptx files I wish to read does not have animations.